# Acer makes monitor go to power safe mode unless in safe mode

Tags: windows-vista, display, graphics-card, acer-aspire

I have an acer aspire x3200

Monitor says no input signal (go to power safe mode)
I was only able to use computer in safe mode

The computer was on (power safe mode) for two weeks.

The monitor is ok with another desktop

I tried with a different monitor, same message (monitor goes to power safe mode)

Why is this happening and if it's my video card probLem will I be able to replace the video card and solve it?

It's currently using GeForce 8200 
The NVIDIA® GeForce® 8200 motherboard GPU provides DirectX® 10 and HD movies to everyone.

System is  Windows Vista™

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like the computer is attempting to display at a resolution that the monitor cannot handle.  You can try uninstalling the video drivers from safe mode, restarting the computer, and reinstalling the video drivers.

Comment: @BonGart, that’s a bit of an excessive, scorched-Earth solution.

Comment: @Synetech there is no intelligence in your response.  For example, uninstalling WINDOWS would be more of a scorched Earth policy.  If you were to simply update video drivers, old drivers get uninstalled first... so uninstalling them as a diagnostic step is HARDLY as dramatic and drastic as you make it out to be.  Not very helpful after my suggestion on the Meta site, are you?  Not surprised.

Comment: @BonGart you clearly have never uninstalled and re-installed modern video drivers. There is ***nothing*** simple about it; it is a massive ordeal that has *no* bearing on this question if you had bothered to read and understand the issue properly, especially when the solution is as simple as just changing the resolution. I don't know (or care) about your Meta suggestion, but I began posting my answer about 10 minutes before you posted your worthless comment. By the time I thoroughly **tested** my solution (unlike some people), you had posted your useless comment. Go shave your beard you troll.

Comment: It's too bad that there is no down-voting of comments, otherwise we could let the community determine who's response is the better one.

Comment: @BonGart, besides, re-installing the *monitor* drivers is *infinitely* more practical than re-installing the video-card drivers, but then, it doesn't surprise me that you could not think of that.

Comment: @Synetech... but... but... reinstalling drivers is a *schorched Earth* policy... you would NEVER advocate that someone do THAT... in fact, you'd only go out of your way to  negatively comment if someone advocated the reinstallation of drivers.... oh wait.. you'd only do that to me and then advocate the same procedure.  My bad.  Heck, you are *assuming* that there are even specific monitor drivers installed, since with most Windows installations, generic ones are used.

Answer (score 0):

## Cause

It sounds like the video-card is trying to use a mode that the monitor does not support. Because safe-mode uses a simple, basic mode which the monitor *does* support, it works, but booting normally tries to set the bad resolution, so the monitor just ignores it.

## Test

To make sure this is what is happening, you can do a simple test:

1. Boot into normal mode
2. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
3. Type `cmd` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Type `echo` then press <kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, and <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Do you hear a beep? If you do, then Windows is indeed running, but the video-mode is bad so you simply cannot see anything.

## Solution

In this case, you need to manually (blindly) set the resolution to one that the monitor supports.

<sub>Surprisingly, there is no single, easy registry entry that you can change to set the resolution the next time you boot. `:-|`</sub>

<sup>An easy way that you can set the resolution is to select the *Low Resolution (640x480)* mode in the boot menu instead of *Safe Mode*, however, this may not allow you to set the resolution for normal mode.</sup>

The easiest and more reliable way is to boot into normal mode and just use a program to set the resolution:

1. Boot into *Safe Mode with Networking*
2. Download a command-line [resolution setting program](https://www.google.com/search?q=set+resolution+command+line) ([QRes](http://home.no/aksoftware/) is a good one)
3. Extract the program to somewhere easy to remember (for example `C:\res\`)
4. Reboot into normal mode
5. Run the program:

   1. <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
   2. Type the program and its parameters

      - With QRes extracted to `c:\res`, it would be:
        `c:\res\qres /x:640 /y:480 /c:32 /r:60`
   3. <kbd>Enter</kbd>

You should now be able to see your desktop. Set the resolution to a proper resolution that your monitor supports, [like normal](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Change-screen-resolution). (Right-click the monitor in the *Resolution* dialog and select *Identify* first.)

## Prevention

Make sure that your monitor driver is correct to ensure that Windows does not try to set a resolution that the monitor does not support.

Comment: Wow... all that work, when simply uninstalling the video drivers from safe mode and reinstalling them after the computer reboots would take care of a multitude of possibilities (corrupt drivers, updating drivers, resetting resolution, etc.)  But, it doesn't surprise me to see you put me down, and THEN work off my idea.

Comment: *> Wow all that work, when simply uninstalling the video drivers from safe mode and reinstalling them after the computer reboots*   What are you talking about? How is uninstalling and re-installing video cards *easier* than just changing the video mode?   *>  But, it doesn't surprise me to see you put me down, and THEN work off my idea*   What the hell are you talking about‽ How the hell is changing the resolution *anywhere* close to the same thing as uninstalling and re-installing the video card‽ And what the hell are you talking about‽ When did I *ever* "steal" your worthless ideas? Shut it!